# How can I check that DFS is replicating correctly?

Tags: windows-server-2008, replication, dfs-r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [compare the contents of two folders that are replicating by dfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/405043/compare-the-contents-of-two-folders-that-are-replicating-by-dfs)

We use DFS to replicate files to a Disaster Recovery server.

We have a task where we check the DR systems are working correctly. I have been asked to write a document to confirm DFS replication is working.

Both servers are Windows 2008 64-bit.

I've used the Health Report to check backlogged files etc, but this is a little long winded and I'd ideally like a command that would compare the 2 servers and highlight which of the Replication Folders are not fully replicated.

Is there such a command?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540040(VS.85).aspx), and here's a [PowerShell](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/GetDFSRBacklog) script. If they don't do what you need as-is, I'm sure they'd give you a head start at least.